# Trigger that divides data in yearly tables

Tags: mysql, variables, triggers

I've a table named "tabella" and i must to divide this table yearly.
So i've same table repeated for each year...something like tab_2014, tab_2015, etc..

I must to trigger a copy of data, in this tables...
So if i do this, it works:

```
BEGIN
IF YEAR(NEW.data) = 2014 THEN
    INSERT INTO tab_2014 SELECT * FROM tabella WHERE id = NEW.id;
ELSEIF YEAR(NEW.data) = 2015 THEN
    INSERT INTO tab_2015 SELECT * FROM tabella WHERE id = NEW.id;
END IF;
END;
```

But in this case i must to do an "IF" statement for each year..

If I do something like this, it doesn't work:

```
BEGIN

INSERT INTO CONCAT("tab_", YEAR(NEW.data)) SELECT * FROM tabella WHERE id = NEW.id;
END;
```

How can I do?

Comment: The unfortunate part is using concat and then execute a query requires prepared statement and its not supported in mysql triggers as of now. The ugly hack is calling a stored procedure from trigger.

Comment: Why do you need to split the data into separate tables?  This seems like a really, really bad idea.

Comment: @GordonLinoff  full table contains too much record, and select query are slow... So i must to divide table for read in the current year table, but if i update something for the past year, it must update the relative table.
No other solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is generally no good reason to split data into multiple tables.  MySQL gives you two great ways to handle performance as tables get larger.

The first is to use indexes.  The second is to use partitions.

You don't specify what queries are slow, so it is not really possible to suggest any concrete steps.  However, in almost all cases, multiple tables with the same columns are the *wrong* solution.

If you have specific queries that need performance improvements, I would suggest that you ask another question.

Comment: But... How can i split my subtables with this structure: clients -> id | name | surname | date .................. products -> id | id_client | product_name..

So if i want to partition products table by using YEAR(date) of clients table... how can i do? 

Or maybe it's insignificat and i can split products table by another field, to speed up my queries?

Comment: It seems unlikely that both `products` and `clients` would be so large that they both require partitioning.